# How to evaluate Angular expression in child directive and expose it on parent directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that represents a group of objects, let's call it `people`.

This directive has an `ng-repeat` in its template that repeats a child directive, e.g. `person`, which has an expression attribute `personGreeting` which should evaluate on its scope.

Both `people` and `person` use isolate scope.

How can I set up these directives such that I can expose `personGreeting` on the `people` directive and have it be evaluated within the scope of the `person` directive?

Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myPeople = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bob'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Steve'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Joe',
    }]
  })
  .directive('people', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        peopleList: '=',
        eachPersonGreeting: '&'
      },
      template: '<ul><person ng-repeat="currentPerson in peopleList" person-greeting="eachPersonGreeting(currentPerson)"></person></ul>'
    }
  })
  .directive('person', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        personDetails: '=',
        personGreeting: '&'
      },
      template: '<li>{{personGreeting(personDetails)}}</li>'
    }
  })
  .directive('people2', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        peopleList: '=',
        eachPersonGreeting: '@'
      },
      template: '<ul><person-2 ng-repeat="currentPerson in peopleList" person-greeting="{{eachPersonGreeting}}"></person-2></ul>'
    }
  })
  .directive('person2', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        personDetails: '=',
        personGreeting: '@'
      },
      template: '<li>{{personGreeting}}</li>'
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h4>Here we are just using an in-line expression with ng-repeat, which works as you'd expect:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="currentPerson in myPeople">Hello, {{currentPerson.name}}!</li>
  </ul>

  <h4>But what if we have custom directives, `people`, and `person`, and we want to let consumers of our `people` directive specify how each `person` should be greeted without making them override our directive's template, and also have data binding still work?</h4>

  <h4>Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:</h4>

  <people people-list="myPeople" each-person-greeting="'Welcome, ' + personDetails.name + '!'"></people>

  <h4>Neither does this:</h4>

  <people-2 people-list="myPeople" each-person-greeting="Welcome, {{personDetails.name}}!"></people-2>
</body>


</html>
```

I also started delving into the compile, link and controller functions for both of the directives, as well as the $interpolate service, and got it kind of working, but it got really weird and messy, and I couldn't get data binding working, so it felt like wasted effort. I feel like this should be simple, but it doesn't seem to be.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: AngularJS can be a bit daunting for the uninitiated; hang in there!
[This](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication) is an interesting bit on hierarchical directives that might be useful in solving your issue. One thing I noticed off the bat is the lack of the 'require' option for your 'child' directives (e.g. require: '^people' in person, etc.). I think the link I gave you illustrates that fairly well.

Comment: Good video, but I'm not sure how requiring `people` in `person` would actually benefit in this situation. I think that only solves the opposite problem, and also doesn't seem to help with data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I managed to put together a simple guestbook app using the same concept that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/R7s6xE?p=info

```js
angular.module('guestbookApp', [])
  .controller('guestbookCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.latestGuests = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bob'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Steve'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Joe',
    }];
    $scope.newGuest = {
      name: ''
    };
    $scope.addGuest = function() {
      $scope.latestGuests.push(angular.extend(angular.copy($scope.newGuest), {
        id: $scope.latestGuests.length + 1
      }));
      $scope.newGuest.name = '';
    };
  })
  .directive('guestList', function($parse) {
    return {
      scope: {
        guests: '='
      },
      template: '<ul><li guest ng-repeat="currentGuest in guests | limitTo: -5" guest-details="currentGuest"></li></ul>',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        this.greeting = function(scope) {
          return $parse($attrs.greeting)(scope);
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('guest', function($parse) {
    return {
      scope: {
        guestDetails: '='
      },
      template: '{{greeting}}',
      require: '?^guestList',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var updateGreeting;
        if (controller) {
          updateGreeting = function() {
            scope.greeting = controller.greeting(scope);
          };
        } else if (attrs.greeting) {
          updateGreeting = function() {
            scope.greeting = $parse(attrs.greeting)(scope);
          };
        }
        scope.$watch('guestDetails.name', function() {
          updateGreeting();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="guestbookApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="guestbookCtrl">

  <h4>Latest guests:</h4>

  <guest-list guests="latestGuests" greeting="'Welcome, ' + guestDetails.name + '!'"></guest-list>
  
  <h4>Type your name below to sign the guestbook:</h4>
  <input type="text" ng-model="newGuest.name" />
  <button ng-click="addGuest()" ng-disabled="!newGuest.name">Sign</button>
  <div ng-if="newGuest.name">
    <p guest guest-details="newGuest" greeting="'Hello, ' + guestDetails.name + '! Click \'Sign\' to sign the guestbook!'"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how this could be improved please let me know! I still feel kind of yucky about the use of `$parse` and `$watch`, but maybe it's unavoidable?

Comment: What is the use-case for using the `$watch` here? Are there outside elements changing the names of model instances?

Comment: Also - is it a requirement that the `ng-repeat` portion be in the directive template?

Comment: Not sure about whether I need `$watch` or not, but it is being used in this example to "greet" the user as they are typing their name in the box. As for `ng-repeat`, how else would I repeat the guests? I don't want the consumer to have to specify repeat logic.

Comment: I guess it's a difference in style. I think it's needlessly complicating your directive but I see your point in not wanting the consumer to specify the repeat logic.

Given you requirements and after having played around with your plunker yesterday, I think what you have is a very solid solution. I would accept your own response as the answer to this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

How the greeting depends on the user itself?
Is there any way to create a service that knows how to produce customised greeting?

If not, what about Proxy object? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIO2Om7B83s&feature=youtu.be&t=15m1s
I've discovered it yesterday and, from my perspective, it seems that it fits here. You should create proxy object for each guest, inject it to the guest directive and during the link phase put the parsed (done by angular) greeting into the that injected proxy object.

Also, I think that something you're doing can be done on much simpler way than setting the attribute from the outside and parsing that.

Comment: The "greeting" is a simplification for a much more complex directive in my real app, where I need to be able to format tooltip/popover messages nested several directives deep from an outer controller/template. Do you know where I can read more about the Proxy object idea? It was glossed over pretty quickly in the video. Also, if you could, please take a look at the guestbook app in my answer and fork/modify it to how you think it should be. Thanks for the video link, it is definitely worth a watch.

Comment: unfortunately, i do not have anything more on proxy pattern in angular (just https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-in-patterns#proxy, but it is not too relevant to our case).

i think it would be useful if your reproduce your app with same level of depth, but simplified so we could figure out the best design for you.